# How to show that this limit in multivariable calculus DNE

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin^2(x)+3y^2}{|x|+|y|}$$

Ive been trying to do the approach with y=mx or x=my but it just doesn't seem to work. Also tried to apply polar coordinates but not sure how would it work though.

Comment: Who have said the limit is DNE?

Comment: The question, my professor and wolframalpha hahah

Comment: No. the limit exists

Answer (score 4):

Note $\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{|x| + |y|} \leq \sin(x) \dfrac{\sin(x)}{|x|}$ and $\dfrac{3y^2}{|x| + |y|} \leq 3|y|.$

Comment: And how exactly would this solve the problem? Sorry if it should be obvious, I'm still beginning with multivariable limits and doesn't remember my professor talking about this detail

Comment: If $a \to 0$ and $b \to 0$, so does $a+b,$ that is $a+b \to 0.$

Comment: but this function's limit doesnt exist, thats what I have to proof. the question says it, the professor, and also wolframalpha that the lim doesn't exist

Comment: They are all wrong. The limit exists and is zero.

Comment: The first inequality introduces discontinuities at points where the original function is continuous, for example $(x,y)=(0,1)$. You can replace the RHS with a function which is equal to $0$ for $x=0$ and what you wrote for $x\ne 0$ to make the argument more rigorous.

Answer (score 3):

$$0\leq \frac{\sin^2(x)+3y^2}{|x|+|y|}\leq \frac{\sin^2(x)}{|x|}+\frac{3y^2}{|y|}=|x|\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}+3|y| \to 0$$

as $(x,y)\to (0,0).$

Comment: What this says? that the limit is 0? Because I should prove that it doesn't exist

Comment: Where does the second inequality come from?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos if $a > b$ then $1/a < 1/b,$ notice that $|x|+|y|$ is a bound for both $|x|$ and $|y|.$ If anyhing, we should be careful about the points $(x,y)$ in the axes.

Comment: @WillM. I fail to see the connection between “if $a>b$ then $1/a<1/b$” and the inequality$$\frac{\sin^2(x)+3y^2}{|x|+|y|}\leq \frac{\sin^2(x)}{|x|}+\frac{3y^2}{|y|}.$$Care to explain?

Comment: $\dfrac{\sin^2(x) + 3y^2}{|x|+|y|} = \dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{|x|+|y|} + \dfrac{3y^2}{|x|+|y|} \leq \dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{|x|} + \dfrac{3y^2}{|y|}.$